# How can I reload the .ycm_extra_conf.py file in YouCompleteMe?

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

In the YCM documentation, it says that "YCM looks for a .ycm_extra_conf.py file [...]; when the file is found, it is loaded (only once!)".

Is it possible to reload this file after Vim has already started? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [this merge](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/pull/3023), `:YcmRestartServer` will reload your config.